How can I request with form-data in Cloudfront?
I have deployed my backend code in ec2 and frontend code in s3 with cloudfront.
When I send a request with files, I get html response and the request isn't sent to the server.
This is when I request with files

all other requests are fine but only when I upload files, it has this issue.
and uploading files works well in my local pc.
For ec2 behavior
Viewer protocol policy = HTTP and HTTPS

Allowed HTTP methods = GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

Cache key and origin requests = CachingDisabled

Origin request policy - optional = Allviewer

Is there a configuration setting for file upload in cloudfront?
============================
This is the header sent to the server and the file size is less than 1MB


show me the header you are sending with form data and tell me the size of file

I attached the information

in origin request policy in cloudfront have you added policy to allow Content-Type & Content-Length, because if you dont CF might handle the file upload properly

I set the origin request policy AllViewer. All headers, cookies, query strings. Isn't this correct?

i mean `origin header request policy

I didn't add anything. is origin header request policy in cloudfront? I can only see origin request policy
